# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string When using parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently working with a report application. There is a query that I have to take results BETWEEN two dates. The query is as follows,

```
sqlFreeVal = "SELECT FreePro, (SUM(FreeQty) * FreePrice) AS FreeValue, VAT, VATAmount FROM InvoiceDetails INNER JOIN InvoiceHeader ON ";
sqlFreeVal = sqlFreeVal + "InvoiceDetails.CompanyCode = InvoiceHeader.CompanyCode AND InvoiceDetails.StockiestID = InvoiceHeader.StockiestID AND ";
sqlFreeVal = sqlFreeVal + "InvoiceDetails.DailySalesID = InvoiceHeader.DailySalesID AND InvoiceDetails.RepID = InvoiceHeader.RepID AND InvoiceDetails.InvID = InvoiceHeader.InvID ";
sqlFreeVal = sqlFreeVal + "WHERE InvoiceDetails.StockiestID = '" + StockistID + "' AND FreeQty > 0 ";
sqlFreeVal = sqlFreeVal + "AND InvoiceHeader.SalesDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 ";//InvoiceHeader.SalesDate <= '" + toDT + "' ";
sqlFreeVal = sqlFreeVal + "GROUP BY FreePrice, FreePro, VAT, VATAmount ";
```

Then I'm Executing it using below code,

```
SqlCommand queryFree = new SqlCommand(sqlFreeVal, myConnection);
queryFree.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", fromDT);
queryFree.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", toDT);
SqlDataAdapter adpFree = new SqlDataAdapter(queryFree);
adpFree.Fill(freeTbl);
```

When I run this it gives me the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." Error.
My table has the "datetime" Data type.

Please Help!. Thank You.

Comment: That query ***isn't*** properly parametrized - you're still concatenating the `StockistID` into the query - stop doing that - right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like fromDT and toDT are strings. Just parse them into a DateTime struct before sending.

`queryFree.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Parse(fromDT));`
`queryFree.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", DateTime.Parse(toDT));`

If there is a format problem in your strings, it would throw a FormatException. From there, you can diagnose the problem.

Comment: @KelumSrimal if your problem is solved then mark it As accepted answer , see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers